Taking international flight, but skipping first leg of flight operated by different airline
I understand that remainder of the journey is normally forfeited if the traveller misses the first leg of the flight. But I have a slightly different query.
I have a booking made through Qatar airways to fly from Darwin (Aus) to London Heathrow (GB). The itinerary is DAR-MEL-DOH-LHR. The DAR-MEL leg is operated by Qantas and is a domestic flight and the MEL-DOH-LHR is operated by Qatar airways.
Do you think it will be an issue if I were to checkin for all the flights online and then skip the domestic leg of the itinerary, then board in MEL? Does the remainder itinerary get automatically cancelled even if the flight that was skipped is operated by a different airline and is a domestic one?
Changing the booking would incur a cancelation fee and a bit more costly new ticket.

Are you planning to check a bag?

Yes, might need to check a bag at MEL airport.

Are all the legs on the same ticket? Or these are separate reservations? If it's the same ticket, it doesn't matter which airline operates which, if you check in and don't show up the whole ticket will be forfeited.

Yes, they are all under the same booking.

No can do . If you don't board in Darwin, the rest of your itinerary will be cancelled (baggage or not). Don't do it!

There was a point in the past where this might have worked. And with select pairings of airlines it might still work - depending on how well integrated the various airlines systems are. However I would say that it's unlikely to work on a Qantas/Qatar pairing.
This will almost certainly be a Qatar Airways ticket, with a Qantas leg on it. When you board your flight from Darwin, Qantas will notify Qatar that you've done so (they will "pull the coupon" for that flight - a term that comes from the days when they actually remove the coupon for that flight from your physical paper ticket - although it's all done electronically now days). They do this not just to let Qatar know you boarded the flight, but because doing that is the trigger than gets them paid when the ticket was booked on another carrier!
By the time you arrive in Melbourne, Qatar will know you didn't fly the first leg of your journey. It's possible they will not have actually canceled your connecting flight, but there's a real chance they will have. Even if they haven't, it will show up at boarding that you were not on the inbound flight.
Given you've said you might need to check a bag in MEL, you're definitely going to come to their attention - to the extent that I would say if you check a bag, your odds of this working are pretty much zero percent.  If you don't check a bag you might be able to slide through, and/or try and lie and convince the Qatar staff you did take the initial flight - but your odds of it working are low.
There's can also be further issues, such as what happens if your DRW-MEL flight is delayed.  In this case the airlines will potentially proactively re-route you onto a later MEL-DOH flight, or even onto a completely different route (eg, DWR-BNE-DOH or DWR-SIN-DOH).
One way or another, this is asking for trouble. I can't say with certainty you can't pull it off, but your odds are low, and you risk losing the entire ticket (including your return if there is one) if you try.

Thanks Doc, this makes sense. Probably not worth taking a risk and be unable to board the plane. I shall try once again sweet talking to Qatar and see if they can do something, if not then cancel and re-book again.

You can contact airline (before the first flight) and check if they can do something. When there are good reasons, and it is not a way to get cheaper fares, airlines may be more willing to do such changes. Unfortunately if it is not listed in the condition of the ticket you cannot expect nothing more than the answer tell you, but sometime things get changed. Worst case you get a NO (and 5 minute of your time), so risk free.

very optimistic to expect just 5 mins of interaction lol

So, I got in touch with them and asked if I can skip DAR-MEL and board at MEL; and as expected I was told no can do. The assistant told me they can’t “reroute” the original ticket and I’d have to cancel and rebook. I insisted that it wasn’t a reroute, so he transferred me to another assistant, who agreed to take the first leg out of the itinerary for a change fee, which for me works out a lot cheaper than rebooking or flying back to DAR. I still think there may be a chance like mentioned in this answer, but alas, it turns out I’m not going to be the one to test it. :)

Also, it took over an hour of interaction

It is very much a re-route. You purchased a ticket from DRW-LHR, and now you want to fly MEL-LHR. Those are two very different routes, and the flights will likely have very different prices. This is exactly how hidden-city ticketing works - even if that's not why you purchased it this way!

Honestly this is a very surprising outcome, I'd expect the ticket to be repriced, not just charged a change fee. This is highly unusual and probably not representative. You may have worn them down or they were inclined to help you for whatever reason, but I'd say consider yourself lucky.

@littleadv Very possible it was repriced, but the new price was the same as the old. Thus change fee only.
